# Permissions needed to like a comment / picture / story

Tags: php, facebook, graph

I would like to do the following (if possible).

- Like a comment
- Like a picture

What I have:

Permissions:

**publish_stream, user_likes, offline_access**

When I try to like a story:

```
{
    "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

I've tried with a token of another app that I have allowed myself, and it works, but it's not that easy to derive the correct permissions from it.

So; Which **permissions** do i **need** to **like a comment/img**?
(if possible the correct name of that permission)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your permissions & code. You only need the `publish_stream` permission:
[**Comments**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/#likes)

> You can like a `comment` by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   `COMMENT_ID/likes` with the `publish_stream` permission. No parameters
>   necessary.

[**Status**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/#likes)

> You can write to the `STATUS_MESSAGE_ID/likes` connection to like the
>   status message by issuing an HTTP POST request with the
>   `publish_stream` permission. No parameters necessary.

Comment: Has this answered your question? I'm having the same problem, can't like any image even though I have publish_stream permission

Comment: @jbkkd what is the error you are getting? are you sure the user can actually like the image (privacy settings)? I would recommend creating a new question with detailed desc. about the issue.

Comment: proper permission to request is `publish_actions` now, see: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you can’t publish likes via apps/Graph API at all.

Comment: Oops sorry, I must’ve confused that with likes for fan pages, because that question came up at work a few days ago.